# TikZ and Tabular - Connect Cells with Lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-pic

I would like to connect the cells with the same color using diagonal lines. How can I do that with TikZ? I have tried using overlay and remember picture, but it somehow shifts the entire table.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
     D & I\\
    \hline
    \color{red}$x^2$   &       $\cos x$\\
    \color{blue}$-2x$    &   \color{red}$\sin x$ \\
    \color{orange}$2$     &   \color{blue}$-\cos x$ \\
    $0$& \color{orange}$-\sin x$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nicematrix` package makes it easy to use `tikz` commands inside a matrix.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 3pt}
\begin{NiceArray}{c|c}
    D               &   I\\ \hline
    \color{red}x^2  &   \cos x\\
    \color{blue}-2x &   \color{red}\sin x \\
    \color{orange}2 &   \color{blue}-\cos x \\
    0               &   \color{orange}-\sin x
\CodeAfter
  \tikz{
    \draw[red] (2-1.east)--(3-2.west);
    \draw[blue] (3-1.east)--(4-2.west);
    \draw[orange] (4-1.east)--(5-2.west);
    \draw (5-1.east)--(2-2.west);
  }
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```